# merge table with update ms sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

I need help with one update- insert with merge in sql
Here is the original Insert

```
INSERT INTO [WarehouseMgmt].[JobSteps]
([JobId],[StepName],[StepNo],[ExecName])
VALUES
(N'HOURLY_JOB', N'SyncReportServerReports', 4210, N'WarehouseMgmt.SyncReportServerReports'),
(N'MANUAL_JOB', N'SyncReportServerReports', 4210, N'WarehouseMgmt.SyncReportServerReports'),
(N'HOURLY_JOB', N'SyncReportServerUserEntries', 4220,N'WarehouseMgmt.SyncReportServerUserEntries'),
(N'MANUAL_JOB', N'SyncReportServerUserEntries', 4220, N'WarehouseMgmt.SyncReportServerUserEntries'),
(N'HOURLY_JOB', N'SyncReportServerUsers', 4230,N'WarehouseMgmt.SyncReportServerUsers'),
(N'MANUAL_JOB', N'SyncReportServerUsers', 4230, N'WarehouseMgmt.SyncReportServerUsers'),
(N'HOURLY_JOB', N'StageFactReportServerExecutionLog', 4240, N'WarehouseStaging.StageFactReportServerExecutionLog'),
(N'MANUAL_JOB', N'StageFactReportServerExecutionLog', 4240, N'WarehouseStaging.StageFactReportServerExecutionLog'),
(N'HOURLY_JOB', N'SyncFactReportServerExecutionLog', 4250, N'WarehouseMgmt.SyncFactReportServerExecutionLog'),
(N'MANUAL_JOB', N'SyncFactReportServerExecutionLog', 4250, N'WarehouseMgmt.SyncFactReportServerExecutionLog')

INSERT WarehouseMgmt.SyncJobSteps
(
    JobStepId,
    StepType,
    SyncDataSQLId
)
SELECT 
    JobStepId = JS.Id,
    StepType = 'SQL',
    SyncDataSQLId = SSD.Id
FROM WarehouseMgmt.JobSteps JS
JOIN 
(
    VALUES
        ('SyncReportServerReports',  'WarehouseMgmt.DimReportServerReports'),
        ('SyncReportServerUserEntries',  'WarehouseMgmt.DimReportServerUserEntries'),
        ('SyncReportServerUsers',  'WarehouseMgmt.DimReportServerUsers'),       
        ('StageFactReportServerExecutionLog',  'WarehouseStaging.FactReportServerExecutionLog'),
        ('SyncFactReportServerExecutionLog',  'WarehouseMgmt.FactReportServerExecutionLog')

) V([SyncJobStep], [SQLDataObjectName])
ON JS.StepName=V.[SyncJobStep]
JOIN WarehouseMgmt.SyncSQLData SSD ON V.[SQLDataObjectName]=SSD.ObjectName
```

and i want to have this i my table

```
INSERT INTO [WarehouseMgmt].[JobSteps]
([JobId],[StepName],[StepNo],[ExecName])
VALUES
(N'HOURLY_JOB', N'SyncReportServerReports', 4210, N'WarehouseMgmt.SyncReportServerReports'),
(N'MANUAL_JOB', N'SyncReportServerReports', 4210, N'WarehouseMgmt.SyncReportServerReports'),
(N'HOURLY_JOB', N'SyncReportServerUserEntries', 4220,N'WarehouseMgmt.SyncReportServerUserEntries'),
(N'MANUAL_JOB', N'SyncReportServerUserEntries', 4220, N'WarehouseMgmt.SyncReportServerUserEntries'),
(N'HOURLY_JOB', N'SyncReportServerUsers', 4230,N'WarehouseMgmt.SyncReportServerUsers'),
(N'MANUAL_JOB', N'SyncReportServerUsers', 4230, N'WarehouseMgmt.SyncReportServerUsers'),
(N'HOURLY_JOB', N'SyncReportServerFormatEntries', 4240,N'WarehouseMgmt.SyncReportServerFormatEntries'),
(N'MANUAL_JOB', N'SyncReportServerFormatEntries', 4240, N'WarehouseMgmt.SyncReportServerFormatEntries'),
(N'HOURLY_JOB', N'SyncReportServerReportFormat', 4250,N'WarehouseMgmt.SyncReportServerReportFormat'),
(N'MANUAL_JOB', N'SyncReportServerReportFormat', 4250, N'WarehouseMgmt.SyncReportServerReportFormat'),
(N'HOURLY_JOB', N'StageFactReportServerExecutionLog', 4260, N'WarehouseStaging.StageFactReportServerExecutionLog'),
(N'MANUAL_JOB', N'StageFactReportServerExecutionLog', 4260, N'WarehouseStaging.StageFactReportServerExecutionLog'),
(N'HOURLY_JOB', N'SyncFactReportServerExecutionLog', 4270, N'WarehouseMgmt.SyncFactReportServerExecutionLog'),
(N'MANUAL_JOB', N'SyncFactReportServerExecutionLog', 4270, N'WarehouseMgmt.SyncFactReportServerExecutionLog')

INSERT WarehouseMgmt.SyncJobSteps
(
    JobStepId,
    StepType,
    SyncDataSQLId
)
SELECT 
    JobStepId = JS.Id,
    StepType = 'SQL',
    SyncDataSQLId = SSD.Id
FROM WarehouseMgmt.JobSteps JS
JOIN 
(
    VALUES
        ('SyncReportServerReports',  'WarehouseMgmt.DimReportServerReports'),
        ('SyncReportServerUserEntries',  'WarehouseMgmt.DimReportServerUserEntries'),
        ('SyncReportServerUsers',  'WarehouseMgmt.DimReportServerUsers'),
        ('SyncReportServerFormatEntries',  'WarehouseMgmt.DimReportServerFormatEntries'),
        ('SyncReportServerReportFormat',  'WarehouseMgmt.DimReportServerReportFormat'),
        ('StageFactReportServerExecutionLog',  'WarehouseStaging.FactReportServerExecutionLog'),
        ('SyncFactReportServerExecutionLog',  'WarehouseMgmt.FactReportServerExecutionLog')

) V([SyncJobStep], [SQLDataObjectName])
ON JS.StepName=V.[SyncJobStep]
JOIN WarehouseMgmt.SyncSQLData SSD ON V.[SQLDataObjectName]=SSD.ObjectName
```

I cannot use only INSERT,because there are already values in database and i don't want to delete them.How can i update 4 values in my first Insert and and 4 new. Look carefully first insert and second

I want something like this

```
MERGE [WarehouseMgmt].[JobSteps] JS
USING #JobSteps TJS
ON(TJS.[StepName] = JS.[StepName])
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
THEN INSERT ([JobId],[StepName],[StepNo],[ExecName]) 
VALUES 
(N'HOURLY_JOB', N'SyncReportServerFormatEntries', 4240,N'WarehouseMgmt.SyncReportServerFormatEntries'),
(N'MANUAL_JOB', N'SyncReportServerFormatEntries', 4240, N'WarehouseMgmt.SyncReportServerFormatEntries'),
(N'HOURLY_JOB', N'SyncReportServerReportFormat', 4250,N'WarehouseMgmt.SyncReportServerReportFormat'),
(N'MANUAL_JOB', N'SyncReportServerReportFormat', 4250, N'WarehouseMgmt.SyncReportServerReportFormat')
WHEN MATCHED
THEN UPDATE JS.[StepNo] = TJS.[StepNo] ;
```

Why this is wrong ?

Comment: Create a temporary table and insert those "new" values in there. Then you can join it just like any other table and complete the insert.

Comment: i cannot use temp table, i need merge statement that will update my rows and insert new rows

Comment: It is possible to create a table variable with DECLARE syntax. It will be gone in the next batch. Are there really specific restrictions that permit creation of this kind of variable?

Comment: no there are no restirctions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a table valued constructor in your merge statement as the source table in almost the same way you do in a select, so instead of:

```
SELECT Column1, Column2
FROM (VALUES (1, 2), (3, 4)) AS v (Column1, Column2)
```

You can use:

```
MERGE [TableName] AS t
USING (VALUES (1, 2), (3, 4)) AS v (Column1, Column2)
    ON t.Column1 = v.Column1
WHEN MATCHED etc...
```

So for your first example you would end up with:

```
MERGE [WarehouseMgmt].[JobSteps] AS js
USING 
(   VALUES
        (N'HOURLY_JOB', N'SyncReportServerReports', 4210, N'WarehouseMgmt.SyncReportServerReports'),
        (N'MANUAL_JOB', N'SyncReportServerReports', 4210, N'WarehouseMgmt.SyncReportServerReports'),
        (N'HOURLY_JOB', N'SyncReportServerUserEntries', 4220,N'WarehouseMgmt.SyncReportServerUserEntries'),
        (N'MANUAL_JOB', N'SyncReportServerUserEntries', 4220, N'WarehouseMgmt.SyncReportServerUserEntries'),
        (N'HOURLY_JOB', N'SyncReportServerUsers', 4230,N'WarehouseMgmt.SyncReportServerUsers'),
        (N'MANUAL_JOB', N'SyncReportServerUsers', 4230, N'WarehouseMgmt.SyncReportServerUsers'),
        (N'HOURLY_JOB', N'SyncReportServerFormatEntries', 4240,N'WarehouseMgmt.SyncReportServerFormatEntries'),
        (N'MANUAL_JOB', N'SyncReportServerFormatEntries', 4240, N'WarehouseMgmt.SyncReportServerFormatEntries'),
        (N'HOURLY_JOB', N'SyncReportServerReportFormat', 4250,N'WarehouseMgmt.SyncReportServerReportFormat'),
        (N'MANUAL_JOB', N'SyncReportServerReportFormat', 4250, N'WarehouseMgmt.SyncReportServerReportFormat'),
        (N'HOURLY_JOB', N'StageFactReportServerExecutionLog', 4260, N'WarehouseStaging.StageFactReportServerExecutionLog'),
        (N'MANUAL_JOB', N'StageFactReportServerExecutionLog', 4260, N'WarehouseStaging.StageFactReportServerExecutionLog'),
        (N'HOURLY_JOB', N'SyncFactReportServerExecutionLog', 4270, N'WarehouseMgmt.SyncFactReportServerExecutionLog'),
        (N'MANUAL_JOB', N'SyncFactReportServerExecutionLog', 4270, N'WarehouseMgmt.SyncFactReportServerExecutionLog')
) AS v ([JobId],[StepName],[StepNo],[ExecName])
    ON v.JobID = js.JobID
    AND v.StepName = js.StepName
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE
    SET StepNo = v.StepNo,
        ExecName = v.ExecName
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
    INSERT (JobId, StepName, StepNo, ExecName)
    VALUES (v.JobId, v.StepName, v.StepNo, v.ExecName);
```

Then for the second statement, I would encapsulate the new data with a common table expression for clarity, but the principle is the same (although I am not sure example what columns you want to match on or update):

```
WITH NewSyncJobStep AS
(   SELECT  JobStepId = JS.Id,
            StepType = 'SQL',
            SyncDataSQLId = SSD.Id
    FROM    WarehouseMgmt.JobSteps JS
            JOIN 
            (
                VALUES
                    ('SyncReportServerReports',  'WarehouseMgmt.DimReportServerReports'),
                    ('SyncReportServerUserEntries',  'WarehouseMgmt.DimReportServerUserEntries'),
                    ('SyncReportServerUsers',  'WarehouseMgmt.DimReportServerUsers'),
                    ('SyncReportServerFormatEntries',  'WarehouseMgmt.DimReportServerFormatEntries'),
                    ('SyncReportServerReportFormat',  'WarehouseMgmt.DimReportServerReportFormat'),
                    ('StageFactReportServerExecutionLog',  'WarehouseStaging.FactReportServerExecutionLog'),
                    ('SyncFactReportServerExecutionLog',  'WarehouseMgmt.FactReportServerExecutionLog')

            ) V([SyncJobStep], [SQLDataObjectName])
                ON JS.StepName=V.[SyncJobStep]
            JOIN WarehouseMgmt.SyncSQLData SSD 
                ON V.[SQLDataObjectName]=SSD.ObjectName
)
MERGE WarehouseMgmt.SyncJobSteps AS sjs
USING NewSyncJobStep AS n
    ON n.JobStepId = sjs.JobStepId
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET SyncDataSQLId = n.SyncDataSQLId
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
    INSERT (JobStepId, StepType, SyncDataSQLId)
    VALUES (n.JobStepId, n.StepType, n.SyncDataSQLId);
```